# Expand a classification dataframe to include all possible pairs and frequencies by group

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that for simplicity, i made a reproducible example like this:

```
rex <- data.frame(X1 =c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), X2 = c("A","A","A", "A", "B","B","B", "B"), Reference = c('Cat1','Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4','Cat1','Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4'), Classf = c('Cat1','Cat1', 'Cat3', 'Cat5', 'Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', 'Cat4'))
```

The resulting output is something like this

```
  X1 X2 Reference  Classf
1  1  A      Cat1 Cat1
2  1  A      Cat2 Cat1
3  1  B      Cat3 Cat3
4  1  B      Cat4 Cat5
5  2  A      Cat1 Cat1
6  2  A      Cat2 Cat2
7  2  B      Cat3 Cat3
8  2  B      Cat4 Cat4
```

It's a data from a multiclass classification problem, were subjects (in X1: 1 to n) were presented with objects in multiple categories (X2), these objects could be 1 of 4 things in the column `reference`, meaning, each X1 and X2 can take up any value in `reference`, and the classification (classf) will return what subjects thought was the intended reference (although the response has an extra value - Cat5- which is a confusion with a different item not included in reference).
What I am trying to do, is to create a new dataframe, where I can expand the current one, to obtain all possible pairs of `reference` and `Classf`, and count the number of times each level in `X1` for each level of `X2` showed a specific decision pair pattern. if they did not show a specific pair pattern, then the count should be zero,

so something like this

```
  X1 X2 Reference Classf Freq
1  1  A      Cat1   Cat1    1
2  1  A      Cat1   Cat2    0
3  1  A      Cat1   Cat3    0
4  1  A      Cat1   Cat4    0
5  1  B      Cat2   Cat5    1
6  1  B      Cat2   Cat1    0
7  1  B      Cat2   Cat2    0
8  1  B      Cat2   Cat3    0
```

Apologies if this is a bit wordy, this is a simplified version of the problem. Appreciate any pointers.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ccreate a  'Freq' column of 1, then do the grouping by 'X1', 'X2' and expand the dataset with `complete`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
rex %>%
    mutate(Freq = 1) %>% 
    group_by(X1, X2) %>%
    complete(Reference, Classf, fill = list(Freq = 0))
```

---

If we want to do a `count`

```
rex %>% 
   count(X1, X2, Reference, Classf) %>%
   complete(X1, X2, Reference, Classf, fill = list(n = 0))
```

Comment: hi @akrun, thank you for the suggestion, but this solutions seems to only transform frequency into zero and ones, instead of counting it. So, my goal is to use frequency to count the number of times a pattern ```Reference``` by ```Classf``` occurs

Comment: @HelioCuve. Your expected output number of rows is not clear.  So, I wasn't sure.  Added a `count` method

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I figured I could also just to the count from your first solution! works perfectly, thanks